# Why does Dart allow arbitrary types to be thrown as exceptions?

Tags: flutter, dart

In the Dart docs at https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#exceptions, it states the following:

> Dart provides Exception and Error types, as well as numerous predefined subtypes. You can, of course, define your own exceptions. However, Dart programs can throw any non-null object—not just Exception and Error objects—as an exception.

The example they give for this behavior is `throw 'Out of llamas!';`.

Why would I ever want to throw something that isn't an `Error` or `Exception`? What is the design decision behind allowing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you may already have an object that you want to inspect if an error occurs, and can just throw that object, or just so you can throw a string like in the example.

It's worth noting that a `catch` block can optionally catch the stack trace, and since the stack trace is not part of the Exception, it makes sense to allow arbitrary objects to be thrown.

```
try {
  throw 'Error!';
} catch (error, stacktrace) {
  print(stacktrace);
}
```

Many times you will just see `catch (e)` in code, but you may also see `catch (e, s)`.